# How to display a Image on a remote linux machine through ssh

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, xorg

I have two computers, one running windows(WIN7) and the other running linux(SUSe). I'm wondering if there is a way to ssh(Putty) into the linux machine and run a command to have a image display on the linux machine (The image would be stored locally on the linux machine). I know it won't necessarily be just one command that accomplishes something like this but any and all help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's nothing harder than connecting to the Linux machine, setting `DISPLAY` variable to connect to the running X server and running an image viewer. Example:

```
   $ export DISPLAY=:0
   $ ristretto <IMAGE>
```

This assumes that `USER` has a right to connect to the X server instance running on `LINUX` machine. If he doesn't, X server owner must use `xhost` command to allow other clients to connect. There are many image viewers for Linux - I used `ristretto`, `feh`, `xv` - pick the one you like the best.